# Does $\frac{\ln\left(\ln\left(\left|x\right|^{\frac{1}{24}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$ have an asymptote in y=0?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am studying this function and i got pretty stuck on the horizontal asymptote
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\ln\left(\left|x\right|^{\frac{1}{24}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
I checked my limit with Wolfram and other apps so i think it's correct, but i report my reasoning (that i'm not sure about):
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\ln\left(\left|x\right|^{\frac{1}{24}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\ln\left({\frac{1}{24}}\ln\left(\left|x\right|\right)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\ln\left({\frac{\ln\left(\left|x\right|\right)}{24}}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\\=\frac{\ln(\ln(|x|))-\ln(24)}{\sqrt x}=\frac{\infty\space\text{logarithmically}}{\infty\space\text{exponentially}}=0$$
Here i concluded using infinity hierarchy that the limit is $0$, i'm not sure if it's correct but other calculators using L'Hopital get to the same result.
My question is, if the limit for $x\to+\infty$ is finite, the function should have an horizontal asymptote in $y=0$, but for example $f(e^{24})=0$. What am i missing?

Comment: Having the asymptote $y=0$ doesn't mean the function can't take that value before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote as you have illustrated.

It is alright for the value to attain value $0$.
Let's study a simpler a function,

$$g(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\ln |x|^\frac12 \right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Similarly, $g(e^2)=0$ but $y=0$ is an asymptote.[image]